# Word for murder to prevent "snitching"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for a murder of a co-conspirator or witness in order to preclude testimony to the authorities.

For example:

> Many suspect that Fat Tony's apparent fatal accident on the New Jersey
>   Turnpike was in fact a *[word]* perpetrated by other members of the
>   Soho Heist team.

**Update** I know the verb *to silence*, and I was hoping for a snappy noun for, basically, "killing to silence." An *ad hoc* construction becomes unwieldy in my actual usage, which deals with statistics. Perhaps here's a more relevant example:

> According the police, 98 homicides can be traced directly to the
>   crackdown. Only seven resulted from police shootings in the line of
>   duty; the rest were *[word]* by the crime syndicates themselves.

Comment: Not a word for the murder or staged accident itself, but the action to stop a witness from testifying can be referred to as "silencing" the witness.  This can also be accomplished with bribery or intimidation.

Comment: The normal terminology would be that Fat Tony was "silenced".  While there are other possible ways this silence might be obtained, the usual interpretation would be that he was killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the scope is broader than just "to prevent snitching", but ***preemption*** may work here. See the last example in the ODO definition extract below.

> Many suspect that Fat Tony's apparent fatal accident on the New Jersey
>   Turnpike was in fact a (*snitching*) ***preemption*** perpetrated by other members of the Soho
>   Heist team.
>
> According the police, 98 homicides can be traced directly to the
>   crackdown. Only seven resulted from police shootings in the line of
>   duty; the rest were ***preemptions*** by the crime syndicates themselves.

ODO:

> **[preemption](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/preemption)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **2** The action of **preempting** or **forestalling**, *especially of making a preemptive attack*.
>   ‘He summarized much legal and
>   philosophical argument by specifying four criteria of preemption as
>   self-defense.’
>
> **[preempt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/preempt)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Take action in order to prevent (an anticipated event) from happening; forestall.
>   ‘the government preempted a coup attempt’
>   ‘But on this occasion police pre-empted the event and warned drivers
>   to keep away.’
>
> **1.1** Act in advance of (someone) in order to prevent them from doing something.
>   ‘it looked as if she'd ask him more, but Parr
>   preempted her’
>   ‘Velised **pre-empted** him, *causing an ‘accident’ that killed* my mother and my brother Daniel.’

Comment: Excellent. I could even say "preemptive killing" if the murderous aspect isn't clear from the context.

Comment: Actually, _premptive killing_ is what I started with, but noticed that the context of _killing_ has already been set in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, ***to [silence](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/silence)*** is the appropriate expression that is generally used to express the concept of preventing someone from revealing inconvenient facts:

> - to prevent someone from expressing their views or from criticizing or opposing someone:
>
>   - *Big companies file lawsuits to silence their critics.
>       The more they try to silence us, the more we will speak out.
>       **Al Capone silenced his opponents by killing them.***

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- In your sentence you may express the idea saying that Fat Tony's apparent accident was actually a murder perpetrated to silence him....

Answer (score 0):

How about *hit*?

> Many suspect that Fat Tony's apparent fatal accident on the New Jersey Turnpike was in fact a *hit* perpetrated by other members of the Soho Heist team.

From M-W:

> [*hit*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit): a premeditated murder committed especially by a member of a crime syndicate